# Azure-Speaker Recognition API Speaker Recognition - Get Operation Status: Error in the message field getting this error "IncompleteEnrollment"

Tags: c#, azure, api, azure-cognitive-services

I have enrolled a profile and the enrollment status returned is "enrolled".
But when i try to identify the profile from the operation response i get
in message field: "*IncompleteEnrollment*"

From documentation of **Speaker Recognition API Speaker Recognition - Get Operation Status**

Case 4 - failed
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "status": "failed",
  "createdDateTime":  "2015-09-30T01:28:23Z"
  "lastActionDateTime": "2015-09-30T01:35:23Z"
  "message":  "Some failure info"
}

Response for Identification Profile - Get Profile

"identificationProfileId": "13c9ef6d-****-****-****-eff1e12492f6",
  "enrollmentSpeechTime": 33.6,
  "remainingEnrollmentSpeechTime": 0.0,
  "locale": "en-us",
  "createdDateTime": "2020-01-10T10:15:15.931Z",
  "lastActionDateTime": "2020-01-10T10:17:59.953Z",
  "enrollmentStatus": "Enrolled"

As you can see the profile is enrolled. 
But on calling speaker identification the response in operation status is : "IncompleteEnrollment"

{"status":"failed","createdDateTime":"2020-01-10T10:21:24.8108966Z","lastActionDateTime":"2020-01-10T10:21:25.8413525Z","message":"IncompleteEnrollment","processingResult":null}

Answer (score 0):

Could you please make sure they are the same enrollment? Could you please share more details like all relative statuses. You can also use Get Profile API to check if the enrollment was successful or not. Please refer to following:

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c211e597ed22ec38f431

Thanks.

Comment: Response for Identification Profile - Get Profile 

"identificationProfileId": "13c9ef6d-****-****-****-eff1e12492f6",
  "enrollmentSpeechTime": 33.6,
  "remainingEnrollmentSpeechTime": 0.0,
  "locale": "en-us",
  "createdDateTime": "2020-01-10T10:15:15.931Z",
  "lastActionDateTime": "2020-01-10T10:17:59.953Z",
  "enrollmentStatus": "Enrolled"

As you can see the profile is enrolled. 
But on calling speaker identification the response in operation status is : "IncompleteEnrollment"

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact problem, and this is what I found:

when trying to do the Identification, amongst the identificationProfileIds I was submitting, one profile's status was still "Enrolling" (not the profile that I was trying to identify, but it still gave problems). That is why I believe that "IncompleteEnrollment" message was given. I got the status of all my profiles with the GetAllProfiles API, so as the others have already said, you should check it.

When I did again the Identification, removing the profileID of the profile that was still enrolling from the set "identificationProfileIDs", everything worked fine and the identification was successful.

Please refer to the API: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c523778daf217c292592